# Function "pd.read_csv" does not seperate text after comma into another column if it is double-quoted in Python 3.6

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('chat_daniel.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
```

On the following data field:

Date,From,Content

2017-09-14  10:56 AM,"Tim X","jo"

2017-09-14  10:57 AM,"DanieY","Jow k ben thuis"

2017-09-14  10:57 AM,"Tim X","kan ik komem?"

2017-09-14  10:58 AM,"Tim X","ik heb 2 tudsejuren"
etc.

I get the following outcome with print(df.head()):

```
                                            Date  From  Content
```

0                  2017-09-14  10:56 AM,"Tim X","jo"   NaN      NaN

1    2017-09-14  10:57 AM,"DanieY","Jow k ben thuis"   NaN      NaN

2       2017-09-14  10:57 AM,"Tim X","kan ik komem?"   NaN      NaN

3  2017-09-14  10:58 AM,"Tim X","ik heb 2 tudseju...   NaN      NaN

4  2017-09-14  11:00 AM,"DanieY","Ik moet 12 sxho...   NaN      NaN

While I should get (as has been the case in some other things I've done with csv)

```
                                            Date  From  Content
```

0                  2017-09-14  10:56 AM   "Tim X"      "jo"

1    2017-09-14  10:57 AM   "DanieY"      "Jow k ben thuis"

2       2017-09-14  10:57 AM   "Tim X"      "kan ik komem?" etc.

So far searching everywhere I haven't found anyone who has had the same case. I can't remove all double quotes because then all commas in the double quoted fields will create seperate fields.

I've already tried changing Date,From,Content to Date,"From","Content".

Edit: With the following file and code:

Taken away for privacy reasons.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import os
import re
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.read_csv('chat_daniel.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
print(df.head())
print('-'*40)
print(df.info())
```

I get the wrong output.

Edit2 (solution):

If you have this problem, to get it to function in a normal way (assuming your problem is like Jack Daniel describes for me) open an editor other than excel and you will see the problem. I used Sublime Text to easily edit my file to normal without having to do everything manually, after doing that everything should function like normal.

Comment: Please don't post external links that noone wants to read. Try to keep things simple: input, expected output, actual output and code. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem.

Comment: I could not either

Comment: I have edited the post to give you the exact file and code I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been already noted, the reason for your problem is that all fields are stored within a string. You can separate them in pandas for instance like this:

```
import pandas as pd
#read your csv file
temp = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
#split the first column and create new columns for each entry
df = temp["Date"].str.split(",", expand = True)
#rename with old column names
df.rename(columns = dict(enumerate(list(temp))), inplace = True)
print(df)
```

Bonus question: Does Mr D approve that you make the conversation public here?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

As for Mr D, this conversation basically contains messages that are about nothing more but agreeing to chill after school.

Comment: Oh damn, I forgot that I send the whole file....

Well, I'll delete it now.

Comment: I suggest deleting the Dropbox file. I can still see it, when I go into the revision history.

Answer (score 0):

Your csv formatting is wrong. If you open up your csv in terminal or in any text editor, you'll notice the whole record is one big string enclosed in double-inverted commas. This is the reason it is not recognizing the comma separated values because it is one big string and corresponds to first column.